# "Ministra ai trasporti": perché si usa la preposizione "a"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Leggendo questa [notizia su Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2020/05/20/dal-3-giugno-torneremo-a-volare-in-bio-sicurezza), mi sono imbattuta nell'espressione

> ministra ai trasporti.

Ho ricercato con Google e ho trovato altre locuzioni simili:

> - ministro ai giovani e allo sport
> - ministro ai beni culturali
> - ministro alla cultura
> - ministro alla giustizia
> - ministro all'istruzione
> - ministro all'economia
> - ministro agli affari esteri
> - ministro agli affari regionali
> - ...

Persino in un [articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/contenuti/settima-settimana-della-lingua-italiana-nel-mondo/1873) che fa la presentazione della Settimana della lingua italiana nel mondo del 2007 si trova

> Vice Ministro agli Affari Esteri.

C'è qualche modo di capire perché si usa la preposizione "a" in queste espressioni?

Ho letto la voce che riguarda la [preposizione "a" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/a2/), ma non riesco a vedere che corrisponda a nessuno degli usi spiegati.

Comment: In effetti è curioso. A me (il che non vuol dire niente) suona insolito, anche se non del tutto inaudito, e mi sembra non trovi riscontro né nel Treccani sotto “ministro”, né in qualche sito ufficiale di ministero che ho visto a campione: [Ministra delle Infrastrutture e dei Trasporti](http://www.mit.gov.it/ministero/ministro), [Ministro della giustizia](https://www.giustizia.it/giustizia/it/mg_9.page) etc.

Comment: Secondo me è il frutto di una elisione "Ministro (preposto) ai trasporti...

Comment: Io l'ho sentito qualche volta, anche se non ho mai sentito "ministro ai giovani e allo sport". Penso che @RiccardoDeContardi abbia ragione a dire che sia una elisione (e che sia quella elisione).

Comment: "Questo in sintesi il ritratto del nuovo ministro all'Economia Roberto Gualtieri, un politico che prende il posto del tecnico Giovanni Tria." ("La Repubblica")

Answer (score -1):

Sarebbe "ministra assegnata ai trasporti" che a sua volta significa "assegnata ai trasporti col ruolo di ministra".

Quindi si tratta di una omissione verbale di "assegnata" piuttosto che di un uso non documentato della preposizione "a".

In questo caso in particolare la locuzione è usata insieme al nome della ministra.
La differenza percepita da chi legge tra "la ministra ai trasporti, Paola De Micheli, ha spiegato che..." e "la ministra dei trasporti Paola De Micheli, ha spiegato che ..." è che chi scrive vuole portare all'attenzione del lettore

- "il pensiero del ministro assegnato ai trasporti" (che incidentalmente è Paola De Micheli), nel primo caso
- "il pensiero di Paola De Micheli", della quale, per completezza o rispetto, si specifica il titolo, nel secondo caso.

Se non viene specificato il nome della persona chiaramente la funzione di titolo di ministro dei trasporti viene meno, tuttavia qualche differenza semantica rimane:

"- Sai che Paola de Micheli è ministra dei trasporti. - Certo che ha fatto una gran carriera." Paola è una ministra! L'enfasi è sul ruolo.

"Paola de Micheli è ministra ai trasporti, Azzolini lo è all'istruzione, Guerini alla difesa, .....", questi ministri de Micheli, Azzolini, Guerini sono assegnati rispettivamente ai trasporti, all'istruzione, alla difesa... L'enfasi è sul ministero.

Lo stesso ragionamento si applica ad altri ruoli (sottosegretario, presidente, comandante, ...) e altre strutture (regione, caserma, università, ...).

EDIT:

1. "Subsecretario al Ministerio de Infraestructuras y Transportado" in italiano diventa "sottosegretario al ministero delle infrastrutture e trasporti". "Destinado como Ministro al Ministerio de Defensa" = "assegnato come ministro al Ministero della difesa". Anche in spagnolo si può usare la preposizione "a".
2. "Ministero de" può essere omesso se il contesto lo permette (p.es. se si sta parlando di politica) quindi le 2 frasi diventano "Sottosegretario alle Infrastrutture e Trasporti" e "assegnato come ministro alla Difesa". Quest'ultima abbrevviabile in "ministro alla Difesa" che alla lettera significa "uno che è stato assegnato come ministro alla Difesa".

"Commissario al Commercio": si parla di politica? allora, per la regola 2, per commercio non si intende il trading ma il "dipartimento del commercio". Per la regola 1, quel commissario al (dipartimento di) commercio è uno che è stato assegnato al (dipartimento del) commercio come commissario.

"Presidente alla filiale di Vicenza", qui basta la regola 1: si tratta di uno che è stato assegnato alla filiale di Vicenza come presidente.

"Professore di Relatività generale": può mai uno essere assegnato alla relatività generale? no quindi la regola 1 non si può applicare. Ma magari si può applicare la regola 2 e quindi poi la regola 1. Vediamo: con "Relatività generale" si può essere sottinteso qualcosa? p.es. "Centro studi di Relatività generale", "Istituto di Relatività generale", "scuola di specializzazione in Relatività generale"? Allora, se dal contesto si capisce che è stato sottinteso qualcosa e questo contesto è caratterizzato dalla conoscenza di una organizzazione formata da diversi centri studi o istituti o scuole di specializzazione (una di relatività generale, una di magnetofluidodinamica, una di cosmologia quantistica, astrofisica relativistica), allora si può applicare la regola 2 in base alla quale per "relatività generale" in questo contesto significa p.es. "scuola di specializzazione in Relatività generale" e può a sua volta applicarsi la regola 1 che permette di dire "professore alla Relatività generale" intendendo che è un professore che insegna alla scuola di specializzazione di Relatività generale. Diversamente si può solo dire "professore di relatività generale" senza nessuna enfasi su dove insegna ma solo cosa insegna.

Comment: Grazie del tuo contributo. Se ho capito bene questa risposta, si usa anche dire professore alla Relatività generale o presidente alla filiale di Vicenza?

Comment: @Charo La Relatività generale non è una struttura (amministrativa, militare, accademica, privata), quindi si può solo dire professore di Relatività generale, ma si può dire "è professore al dipartimento di fisica" e "è un professore del dipartimento di fisica". "Presidente alla/della filiale di Vicenza" è ok.

Comment: Veramente non riesco a capire molto bene la differenza concettuale per questo tipo di costrutti tra "Relatività generale" e "trasporti":  neanche "trasporti" è una struttura amministrativa.

Comment: Su questa altra [notizia](https://it.euronews.com/2020/08/26/ue-si-dimette-il-commissario-al-commercio-phil-hogan) ho trovato un altro esempio: "Commissario al Commercio".

Comment: @Charo ho aggiunto nella risposta qualche chiarimento relativo ai tuoi ultimi due commenti

Comment: «può mai uno essere assegnato alla relatività generale? no»: No? Chiedilo ai docenti a cui vengono assegnati corsi che non avrebbero scelto di tenere, perché i corsi più appetibili se li sono accaparrati altri! :) Comunque è la prima volta in vita mia che sento tutta questa enfasi sul concetto di “assegnare”.

Comment: @DaG ha espresso molto meglio di me quello che volevo dire nel mio commento precedente.